# Implementing own localization engine in React.js - is it worth it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks

I decided to write my own localisation engine using react hooks.
I don't need too much localisations, just want to display messages depending chosen locale.
I have some questions about performance and etc.

This is my translation component which simply returns message by given key:

```
import React from 'react';
import useLocale from 'store/LocaleContext';

export default ({ k }) => {
  const { messages } = useLocale();

  const msg = messages[k] ? messages[k] : k;

  return <>{msg}</>;
};
```

As you can see it uses react hooks and i have messages asynchronously loaded in context provider.

My app is medium sized project and so I am planing to use 50-100 or more `<Translate k="messagekey" />` component in it.

Does it affects my app performance if so many components are subscribed to one context which has provided about 5-6 KB data? (I mean messages will be about 5-10KB in size).

Is it good to use this engine instead of `react-intl` or `react-i18n`, if I ignore other localisation issues (date, time, currency, number ..., Just for messages)?

---

**Edit:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-localisations-8kynz This is sample codesandbox link.

You can see whole localisation files which I created.

Also I added translate function which doesn't returns component but only translated message. Is it good practice to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you might face using a Context is that every time the Provider updates, it will render. And every time a component renders its children render too (unless they are memoized).

In the case you describe I can think of two scenarios.

Are all messages loaded at once?

If this is the case you will have an initial render and another one after the data is fetched. From this point the data will not change and the Provider will not trigger new renders.

Are messages updated/added several times?

In this case every time the Provider updates all of its children will render. This can be an issue if there are many children and are not memoized.

If your case is the first one I would test if there is any issue managing the data inside a Context.

In the second case you might want to consider other options, like using Redux instead of a Context or possibly one of the libraries you suggest.

In any of the two cases, if you are managing a large amount of information in a single object you might consider using different Context and providing smaller sets of data to different parts of the app.

Comment: I edited post, included codesabdbox link. You can fork it and test it as you want.
Messages are static json files they are never added/updated and not loaded same time, context provides one message file at once, only when user changes language.

Comment: Thanks @MalkhaziDartsmelidze. In the real case will those objects be fetched from a certain url or are you simply importing them from a file?

Comment: They are imported from file, I think it doesn't matters if I import it from file or api

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, if you are importing an object from a file into a Context you could simply import the object directly in the component that needs it, instead of creating a state just for the data which is already in the app.

Comment: No, I think that is not correct if I import locale files in component. Because I have to import it in every component where I need localisations. (50+ components), and also I have to write same code in every component, which is not good practice

Comment: If the code + object is being bundled in a single file then the object is already in this file. Any component can import this object and get the key/value needed. If you are not bundling into a single file then the solution might be different.

Comment: Can you modify sandbox according your solution?

Comment: I'm not able right now but will get back later and share in the sandbox what I mean

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-localisations-mzyw0). It is just a basic implementation that should be improved. You can see that now the Context only handles the language code, the messages objects are imported from the module and used inside the Components.

Comment: Thank you, Alvaro. I checked it, of course it's better implementation because messages aren't passed in every context, but what if I want to load  them asynchronously. If I had 5+ language it would be bad to bundle them together. Can you solve this problem?

Comment: You're welcome. In that case the way to go is to fetch and add them to a global state, as you are using them in several components. And which to use depends on what I mention in the answer. As long as there aren't many components and you are only fetching once I don't think you will see a performance impact, but testing is the best way to be sure.

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze check [this article](https://leewarrick.com/blog/the-problem-with-context/) which describes a very similar situation and the alternatives to approach it.

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro, as you know already I use context API for my app state management but I have provided one or two value as data from my context providers. I read whole article, it describes everything clearly but I think my app is not doing unneccessary renderings. My Translate provider provides only one dynamic state - `currentLanguage`, messages are statically imported as you write above on your codesandbox. So messages is never changing and when current language changes every `Translate` component should be re-rendered. Thank for this article and blog. I bookmarked it already

Comment: I am currently developing my app and have used only about 10-15 Translate function. I think this is only 10% of my app. when I will have full app I will test it with different translating methods, message importing methods, state managements and etc. I will post my results here